# What do file operations look like at assembly level

Tags: file, assembly, filesystems

To my naivete , everything stored in the secondary memory (hard disks) are stored in files. As such I understand of file system as the systematization of the information about each and every block of a file .(This in turn might turn out to be a systematization of the information about inodes) .

So what I wanted to know is what happens at assembly and hardware level when a program intends to do an operation on a file . I tried thinking about it and it was along the following lines .

So if my understanding , which I wrote down in the first paragraph , is correct ,then any read operation demanding a certain number of bytes , let's say X , will divide X by block size to get a result ,say  N , then query the file system for the location of the contents of the first N blocks and fetch the content stored in those locations . If it is a hard disk then the contents are fetched from the disk . But does this reading from disk involve using DMA and hence the communication being controlled through some DMA controller ?

When the required number of bytes are read then do they place the content in the stack of the program executed where a variable will be holding the required number of bytes or the hence obtained contents are placed in some other location , like , heap ?

Similar mechanism I could think of for write operation , where the offset is taken , the required block number is determined , then the new bytes to be written are divided into blocks and the new blocks are updated in the file-system .

Please correct if my above understanding is wrong .

However, I could not think of anything significant for closing of files  and could not figure out the ill effects of not closing files in terms of hardware and assembly .

I have been through the following posts :

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev20.html

and

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev20.html .

Here , I can see the illustration in assembly for writing to a floppy device or doing DMA  but in the following chapter :

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev22.html

which is about file systems I could not exactly find out the assembly level details of file operations . (Although in some of the previous chapters , reading from FAT had been covered but to the best of my memory it used BIOS interrupts ) .

So in a nutshell , what happens at hardware and assembly level during file opening , file reading , file writing and file closing ?

Comment: Are you trying to write a device driver?

Comment: @SomeName : Not currently , just trying to understand what happens at assembly level during file I/O

Comment: During file open, the system uses the given path and file name to locate and open the file. On a typical system with virtual memory, for read / write operations that use DMA or Bus Mastering, the user buffer is locked and translated into a set of physical pages, 4KB in size for X86 systems, and then a list of "descriptors" containing physical addresses and sizes is created and used for the read / write operation. After the read or write, the user buffer is unlocked. File close would released any system created buffers and any memory allocated related to opening the file.

Comment: @rcgldr : Could you elaborate on the internals of the  "locate and open the file" process ?
The pages of memory are to hold the content of the files , right ? And why a list of descriptors instead of one ?

Comment: @rcgldr : Could you point to a source which explains about this user buffer ?

Comment: *then query the file system for the location of the contents of the first N blocks and fetch the content stored in those locations*.  Not exactly.  In a normal modern OS, the kernel's file read implementation will first check if that part of that file's data is cached in RAM (the pagecache) *without* caring about where on disk it came from.  Only if that misses does the VFS / page cache have to find out how to get the data into memory where it can be copied to user-space.  The process that made a `read` system call doesn't know any of this, it just did e.g. `rax=0` / `syscall` (x86-64 Linux)

Comment: Nothing different happens at the assembly level than is expressed in the C code that actually implements file accesses in the operating system's kernel.  There's a tiny bit of magic assembly code that implements the transition from the process's code to the kernel's code, but other than that you don't need to consider what's happening at the assembly level to understand it how it all works.

Comment: I'm a bit intrigued with what exactly the OP means by "the  hardware level".. I will just add a remark that the actual "magic" takes place within the hdd itself :)

Comment: @Primeczar - look at the msdn article about [memory descriptor list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ff540568) . This list is used to program DMA or bus mastering controllers with the memory descriptor list.

Comment: @tum : One of the answers below mention a device-driver being used for this . By hardware level , I meant what device is that device whose driver is being used . Ii just needed  a little overview of the electronic operation of that particular device .

Comment: @PeterCordes : Apart from the cache part , where does the filesystem ,which is a structure about the structure in which information are arranged inside disk , is located ?

Comment: @Primeczar: on disk. Normally the FS includes a master block at the start of the disk that identifies it as an XFS, EXT4, BTRFS, NTFS, HFS+, or whatever filesystem, and what version + feature flags are set. So filesystem drivers will know how to handle the FS. The master block will also have pointers (offsets within the block device) to other stuff, like a bitmap of allocated/free blocks and inodes, the top-level directory inode, and stuff like that. It depends on the design of the filesystem what data structures it uses, but normally the metadata is allocated inside the same partition as data

Comment: Some filesystems let you put the metadata on a separate block device, so e.g. you could have fast directory lookups / listings from metadata (directory structure / file permissions + timestamps) on an SSD, while actual file data goes on a big slow magnetic disk or RAID6 array of such disks.

Comment: @PeterCordes :And even every partition will have a similar block at the beginning to indicate the type of filesystem they contain ? Could you elaborate about the storage of the details of individual files like , is there any table like structure ,like in FAT , that tell which files occupy which blocks ? If yes does this table get loaded in RAM as well ?

Comment: EXT4: pretty classic inode-based fs: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout BTRFS (based on B-trees) : https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/On-disk_Format XFS another inode-based FS designed for I/O and CPU parallelism on big RAID arrays: https://linux.die.net/man/5/xfs / http://www.dubeiko.com/development/FileSystems/XFS/xfs_filesystem_structure.pdf.  These are open-source filesystems that are extensively documented, *and* the actual source code for the drivers are available, too.  Yes of course the block or extent list for an inode gets loaded into RAM when needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Stackoverflow is suggesting to move this discussion to chat , may I move this to a chat so that other people who might want to discuss some queries can also join in ?

Comment: @PeterCordes : I was asking whether the file-system structure gets loaded in RAM because I was wondering if on performance grounds it would be easy to do a look-up or find out the necessary blocks from where data is to be read or written to .

Comment: The "move to chat" link says you don't have enough rep to use SO chat, so it doesn't work.  Anyway, yes of course block lists / extent lists stay cached in RAM in any high-performance OS / filesystem.  Either just as part of the pagecache (holding the on-disk data), or parsed / decoded into in-memory formats as part of filesystem-specific cache data structures.  If you `cat big_file > /dev/null` or whatever other sequential read task, the disk access doesn't keep re-reading the block-list or extent-list for that file for each small `read` all, that stays in memory and only real data is read.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Just to clarify a bit further , basically for every file-system , there must be  a table(or a group of tables or any other such structure) for the book-keeping of the blocks and which file own them . So is this structure on which the query is performed( in case of absence of the information in cache) located at the  beginning of the disk ?

Comment: No, often it's distributed over the disk, with each inode having a list of blocks or extents it owns.  There's typically a free-list somewhere, presumably near the start of the FS, or XFS has per-allocation-group free lists.  FSCK will scan the whole filesystem tree and make sure every block is accounted for and not listed as both free and allocated somewhere, or neither.  The log messages that FSCK for various filesystems print out is a useful clue to how they work; what things can be verified and what kinds of problems can be found.  Google for `fsck ext4`  or w/e to find example output.

Comment: Like [Recover from a corrupted filesystem when fsck do not help](//askubuntu.com/q/381518)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks a lot . If it is distributed all through out the disk then how are the locations of all those tables found out ?  From the master block ?

Comment: @Primeczar: From the filesystem object you're looking at.  e.g. a directory entry is a name + pointer to an inode.  An inode has permissions, size, and other metadata, and a list of blocks where the data is stored.  (Or for big files, a pointer to an indirect block that stores the list of data blocks.)  More modern filesystems tend to use start/length *extents* instead of lists of blocks, making it possible to compactly represent the allocated space for a 1GB file.  Anyway, after opening a file, user-space has a "file descriptor"; the kernel side of that has an inode number + file position.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Was just about to type in a question about the assembly level view of the file-descriptor ? And at assembly level how to explain the so called ill -effects of not closing a file-descriptor(file system object)

Comment: A file descriptor is simply an integer index for a file *description* inside the kernel.  (They're per-process, so I guess you'd have a per-process array of file descriptions).  The kernel cleans everything up in a way that's equivalent to `close()` on every open fd, freeing kernel memory etc.  Data is logically written to a file when the `write()` system call returns so it normally doesn't need to do much besides free any kernel memory.  But if that's the last reference to an inode (link count = 0), then closing the last open fd actually lets the inode + data be deleted.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Does every fd  retain the last written bytes of data ? Like, suppose I used an fd to write few bytes , like a string "abcdefgh" , then I used the same fd to write few more bytes , like " cedfghjk" , then will the fd be retaining the previous string "abcdefgh" ?

Comment: @PeterCordes : Basically , needed to understand the gravity of closing the file descriptors , why it is considered as a good practice and why it is a big deal step against memory leaks ?

Comment: No, like I said, a file description is just a reference to an inode, plus an `off_t` file position.  (and a few flags like read-only, write-only, or read+write, and `O_APPEND` or not.)  The *data* goes directly to/from the actual file, not buffered inside the file description.  This is a pretty obvious consequence of the POSIX I/O design where writing on one FD makes data visible right away to reads on other FDs and by other processes.

Answer (score 1):

> What do file operations look like at assembly level

In the application this is done using a system call (e.g. an `int` instruction on x86 CPUs). Such a system call will call a function in the OS.

That function in the OS is typically a short function written in assembly that calls another function which is typically written in a "high-level" programming language (typically C; but writing this function in assembly is also possible of course).

That second function will call a lot of other functions.

On a hard disk or a floppy disk data is stored in form of sectors. Each sector contains a certain number of bytes (for example 512) and you can only read or write complete sectors, not single bytes. The disk does not know anything about files.

In a typical operating system two different types of functions are involved in file handling:

1) The device driver functionality

These functions are there to read or write "sector" data from or to the disk. It depends on the CPU and on the disk drive type how this is actually done.

In the simplest case you have a CPU with memory-mapped I/O and you neither use interrupts nor DMA. The historic Commodore 1581 floppy drive is an example for this.

In this case the software writes some data to the hardware by simply writing a byte to an address - the same way you write a byte to the RAM. Reading from the hardware works like reading a byte from the RAM.

The software will write some data to the hardware that instructs the disk drive to read some data from the disk. Then the software continuously reads data from a certain address. This data contains information if the disk drive is ready. As soon as the disk drive is ready, the software reads the actual data by reading data from another address. Writing works similarly.

If you use a CPU that do not use memory-mapped I/O, accessing the hardware does not work like accessing the RAM, but special instructions (`in` and `out`) are used. (Older x86 computers are an example of this.)

If interrupts are used (as in modern computers), the software does not need to check continuously if the disk drive is ready. A special function - a so-called "interrupt handler" - will be called by the CPU as soon as the disk drive reports to be ready.

If DMA is used (as in modern computers), the disk drive can directly write the data read from the disk to the RAM (or read the data to be written from the RAM). So the software only needs to write the special data that instructs the disk drive to write some sector. The software does not have to write the actual data that shall be written to the disk because the disk drive will directly read this data from the RAM. (The same is true for reading.)

2) The file system functionality

These functions will call the "device driver" functions to access the disk.

A file system is more or less nothing but some description how files are stored on a disk. If a disk uses the "FAT16" file system, there are three areas on a disk: The FAT, the root directory and the clusters.

(On file systems using "inodes" this is a bit different; however, the principle is the same.)

The FAT contains information about where some files are stored on a disk and which clusters are free. The root directory contains information about the names (and some more information such as the file size) of the files on the disk. And the clusters contain the actual file data.

When writing a file to the disk, the file system functions will read the sectors of the FAT (by calling the functions of the "device driver"). It will check the content of the FAT for free clusters. Now it will read the root directory, add the file name of the file written and write the root directory back to the disk. Then the functions will write the actual data of the file to the clusters. In the end, the functions will update the FAT (the corresponding sectors are no longer free) and the root directory (the file size is no longer zero) data and write this information back to the disk.

Comment: *a CPU without memory-mapped I/O*.  x86 *has* memory-mapped I/O, and it's widely in modern device drivers, AFAIK!  `in`/`out` are slow and avoided when possible.  (PCI / PCIe does have separate IO vs. memory address spaces, but devices can have some / all of their MMIO registers in memory space.)  On a modern Linux system, use `lspci -v` to see the memory and IO ranges for each device.  Many only have memory, and often only 256 bytes or 2k or 4k or something (to hold a few MMIO registers).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. I changed "without memory-mapped I/O" to "that does not only have memory-mapped I/O". Of course any CPU (that does not only have on-chip memory) can do memory-mapped I/O.

Comment: You're still claiming that x86 definitely uses `in`/`out` to talk to hardware or set up DMA.  According to `lspci -v`, my NVMe SSD doesn't have any I/O ports, only 16k memory mapped I/O space, so it will definitely use normal loads/stores to program the DMA transfers.  Same for my `e1000e` ethernet for NFS.  According to http://lateblt.tripod.com/atapi.htm, ATA PIO did use stuff like `rep insw` to transfer a sector, so your description is accurate there. 
 But https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input/output says CPU-driven transfers can be described as PIO for either memory or IO ports.

Comment: x86 has non-memory-mapped I/O, but it's avoided by many modern devices for performance reasons, even when bulk transfers are done with DMA.

Comment: @MartinRosenau : The device driver that you mentioned here , what device is it exactly for ? Could you give a small overview of the electronic operation of that device driver ?

Comment: @MartinRosenau : "The software will write some data to the hardware that instructs the disk drive to read some data from the disk"
By this do you mean writing instructions to something like the command register of that device ?

Comment: @Primeczar Exactly. The device driver will write instructions to the command register (and all the other registers) of some device. Because different types of device (e.g. Floppy, IDE hard disk, SATA hard disk, SD card ...) use different hardware (and therefore different command registers etc.), there are different drivers for different kinds of devices.

Comment: @MartinRosenau : These devices , convert the magnetization on the disk drives to electronic signals , right ?

Comment: @Primeczar Depending on the type of the device: SSD devices work differently than magnetic disks.